Spring integration JMS channel error - SpelEvaluationException: EL1078E
I recently upgraded my spring boot app from spring 5 to spring 6 along with other dependency jars.
App uses spring integration to consume messages from queue and process it with other downstream systems.
After the upgrade, started seeing below error -
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.**SpelEvaluationException**: **EL1078E: Concatenated string is too long, exceeding the threshold of '100,000' characters** at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpPlus.checkStringLength(OpPlus.java:158)
From the error it seems, spring integration is not able to take message larger the 100k characters length, app was able to consume these size messages before version upgrade.
I did try to find out this limit length and looks like it is hard coded in spring -
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73d30dd875affac7dc69232bf4c6b183e0801c26/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/OpPlus.java#L58
Does anyone know if there is any other way to fix this error ?

I don't see that there is such a property to configure that limit. It is really hard-codded in the OpPlus. The problem is not upgrade of Java version, but rather you have upgraded Spring Framework from some old version. See Javadocon that OpPlus.MAX_CONCATENATED_STRING_LENGTH.
Also, the problem is not with the mentioned <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>, but rather somewhere downstream where you do such a huge concatenation in SpEL.
Consider to move that logic into Java method call if you really have to do this concatenation.

Yeah, I know spring introduced this validation from version 5.2.24.
Problem is the app uses some Spring features that depend on the underlying Spring version like  Expression Language (SpEL).
I just upgraded the app from spring 5.2.0 to 6.1.5 along with spring boot version upgrade. Not sure if I should raise a bug on spring  GitHub project.
App is heavily relying on spring integration to read messages from JMS queue and then process them with other downstream integrations channel. Moving all this to java is not an option considering the problem is relying in spring framework.

Hoping there would be some spring property we can set in the spring application context which can override this logic similar to this -
spring.context.expression.maxLength
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/evaluation.html#expressions-parser-configuration

I'm not sure why you treat it as a problem since this probably was done to mitigate some vulnerability with SpEL. I didn't mean to move everything to Java: just that expression part where you make such a huge concatenation. You can just have a bean with some specific method to be called from that expression instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/bean-references.html

Thanks @Artem Bilan for guiding in the right direction, the issue was with the spring-integration logging-channel-adapter which was consuming the whole payload attribute into the expression. And this newer version of spring-expression doesn't allow characters more than 100,000.
